# Angular Dynamic Configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-ad-msal

All,

I have a question about how to provide some run time configuration options to my Angular Web Application.
Below are the details, but what I’m after is to be able to compile my Angular Web Application once and then deploy it across multiple environments and only have to  change the endpoints.

What I’m finding, is that once the JSON file below is imported into the app.module.ts file and referenced, at compile time, the values are hard coded into the application, so that when I move the application over to our test servers and try and run the application, once the MSAL authentication occurs and it redirect’s back to the wrong Uri.

Basically it’s not reading the auth-config.json file at run time, but at compile time. Is there a way to make it read it at run time?

I’m working with the package from Microsoft for MSAL / Azure AD authentication.

It uses a json file called auth-config.json. Here is a snippet of it

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "redirectUri": "https://SomeWebSiteName-D.domainname.com",
        "postLogoutRedirectUri": " https://SomeWebSiteName-D.domainname.com "
    },
    "apiBaseUrl": "https://SomeWebSiteNameAPI-D.domainname.com/api/"
}
```

This json file is imported into the app.module.ts file like so.

```
import * as auth from '../assets/config/auth-config.json';
```

It’s then used to configured the MSAL package. This is one of the functions that references some of the data from it.

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: auth.credentials.clientId,
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + auth.credentials.tenantId,
      redirectUri: auth.configuration.redirectUri
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
  });
}
```

Later in the App.module.ts file, the above function is referenced in the providers section of

```
@NgModule
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular gives a solution on how to manage environment-specific variables.

You have an `environments` folder somewhere that has 2 files in it. Here you can specify such imports. Depending on your `angular.json` file these will automatically be exchanged if your environment changes ([Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults)).

So this is where you'd write it instead:

```
// environment.ts
export const environment = {
    "configuration": {
        "redirectUri": "https://SomeWebSiteName-D.domainname.com",
        "postLogoutRedirectUri": " https://SomeWebSiteName-D.domainname.com "
    },
    "apiBaseUrl": "https://SomeWebSiteNameAPI-D.domainname.com/api/"
}

// environment.<specific_environment>.ts
export const environment = {
    "configuration": {
        "redirectUri": "different keys",
        "postLogoutRedirectUri": "..."
    },
    ...
}

// msal-instance.factory.ts
import {environment} from '../path/to/environment';
environment.configuration;
```

#### Update: Providing an example upon your request in the comments

To change the environment at runtime you have multiple options. I will outline an example here;

```
interface Environment {
  configuration: {
    redirectUri: string,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: string,
  },
  apiBaseUrl: string;
}

const environments: Record<string, Environment> = {
  production: {
    "configuration": {
      "redirectUri": "https://SomeWebSiteName-D.domainname.com",
      "postLogoutRedirectUri": "https://SomeWebSiteName-D.domainname.com"
    },
    "apiBaseUrl": "https://SomeWebSiteNameAPI-D.domainname.com/api/"
  }
}

export let environment: Environment;

export const updateEnvironment = (env: string) => {
  environment = environments[env];
}

// 'production' may be an environment variable instead of directly being a string
updateEnvironment('production');
```

Comment: Keimeno thanks for providing the documentation. I have reviewed and I would like a point of clarity. The documentation implies that I can have different files for different environments, but that the files are used to replace the environment.ts file when the application is compiled, is that correct?

if so, this is not what I'm after, I don't want to have to re-build the application between each environment.

I want to build the application and have it read the configuration file at runtime to set the values. Is this possible?

Comment: @David I've updated my answer accordingly. Yes, in my first example the `environment.ts` file is only changed during the build step. With my updated answer you are now able to change the environment, and all environment variables during the runtime.

Comment: @Keimeno Instead of dynamic config at run-time, how about dynamic config during CI/CD?  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75739450/how-to-provide-variables-to-an-angular-build) has the details.  Can you answer it?

Comment: @BrentArias I can take a look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can follow

- Use a json file to store configurations
- Read the json file content
- Use configurations

**Configuration Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Configuration } from './configuration';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigurationService {
  private configData: Configuration | undefined;
  private readonly configPath: string = '/assets/config/configuration.json';
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  async loadConfiguration(): Promise {
    try {
      const response = await this.http.get(`${this.configPath}`)
        .toPromise();
      this.configData = response;
      return this.configData;
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
  }

  get config(): Configuration | undefined {
    return this.configData;
  }
}
```

**App Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Configuration } from './config/configuration';
import { ConfigurationService } from './config/configuration.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export function ConfigLoader(injector: Injector): () => Promise {
  return () => injector.get(ConfigurationService).loadConfiguration();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: ConfigLoader,
    deps: [Injector],
    multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Following article explains it in details.

https://ciemasen.com/articles/how-to-use-angular-dynamic-configuration

Comment: Instead of dynamic config at run-time, how about dynamic config during CI/CD?  This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75739450/how-to-provide-variables-to-an-angular-build) has the details.  Can you answer it?

Comment: attached article referring a json file which you can replace the values in CICD. So you can archive the same using above approach