# How to provide variables to an Angular build?

Tags: angular, npm-scripts

Normally Angular receives its environment settings from environment.[env].ts files when it is built.  However, I have a circumstance where I need the ability to override those settings, at build-time, on the basis of arbitrary parameters like `apiUrl` or `connectionString` passed to the build command.  For example:

> npm run build -- apiUrl=xxx connectionString=yyy

Is there a way to make that work?

The reason why I need this capability, in case it matters, is that the Azure ARM template I'm using to create an Azure Static Web App...is only capable of controlling the "custom build command" generated in the associated github "actions" CI/CD script.  Because I can control the custom build command...then that becomes my one and only opportunity to pass custom / environmental parameters.

Answer (score -2):

What you can do is you can create a separate environment file like "environment.custom.ts" and mention a new configuration namely "custom" inside configurations object in "angular.json" file like below:

```
"configurations": {
        "custom": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.custom.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Now in "environment.custom.ts" you can mention the properties like below:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl : "",
  connectionString:""
}
```

Now while building use the below command:

```
npm run ng build -- --configuration=custom
```

Comment: I stated clearly in my question I don't want the normal Angular configuration approach.  But, this looks like the standard way to supply *hard-coded* configuration to Angular; I'm stuck with whatever values I put into the `environment.custom.ts` file.  I posted this question because I need something different than the "usual" Angular configuration. I need the ability to have *variable* configuration, where my build command is instead `npm run build -- apiURI=https://foobar.com/api`.  This is because I don't know the config values until the last second. Is there a way to do that?